# How can i upload an image from a form of a plugin in october cms?

Tags: php, laravel, plugins, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm tryin to add fileUpload to my multisite plugin ,while adding a new domain i want to upload the country flag of that website.
I trie some things but this error showed up while trying to adisplay the crating new domain form.
error:

```
Model'Keios\Multisite\Models\Setting' does not contain a definition for 'image' october cms
```

i created an other plugin kin which i add the changes i want to create in multisite plugin

```
MultisiteModel::extend(function (MultisiteModel $model){

            $model->attachOne=[
                'flag' => 'System\Models\File'
            ];
        });
```

Comment: The error appears to be in your fields.yml file for the create new domain form. Could you paste that code?

Answer (score 0):

in your model file of your plugin add this :

image should be the name of your field !

```
public $attachOne = [
    'image' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

and then you can call it $model->image for more information look at the doc https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments#file-attachments